Authjs v5 with drizzle and neon
I am trying to implement authentication with authjs v5, drizzle, and neon db. I use the following dependencies:
"@auth/drizzle-adapter": "^0.9.0",
"drizzle-orm": "^0.30.8",
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.15"
The main files are auth.ts and auth.config.ts:
// auth.ts
import { DrizzleAdapter } from "@auth/drizzle-adapter";
import { eq } from "drizzle-orm";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import authConfig from "./auth.config";
import { db } from "./drizzle-app/db";
import { users } from "./drizzle-app/schema";

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  events: {
    async linkAccount({ user }) {
      await db
        .update(users)
        .set({ emailVerified: new Date() })
        .where(eq(users.id, user.id!));
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token }) {
      return token;
    },
  },
  adapter: DrizzleAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  ...authConfig,
});

// auth.config.ts
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default {
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

Also, this is where I export the database:
// db.ts
import { neon, neonConfig } from "@neondatabase/serverless";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/neon-http";
import * as schema from "@/drizzle-app/schema";

// neonConfig.fetchConnectionCache = true;

const sql = neon(process.env.DB_APP_URL!);

export const db = drizzle(sql, {
  schema,
});

Finally, I export the route handlers in /api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { handlers } from "@/auth";

export const { GET, POST } = handlers;

The problem is that in the dev server (I haven't tested live yet), the requests to api/auth/session occur in batches of 12 requests:
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 6085ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 5899ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 114ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 16ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 38ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 13ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 40ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 14ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 37ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 13ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 49ms 
GET /api/auth/session 200 in 21ms 
One duplication would make sense to me since the dev server usually sends two requests, but I can't figure out why so many requests are sent. Any help would be much appreciated.
